# Интересное число. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

> Назовем число интересным, если в нем разность максимальной и минимальной цифры равняется средней по величине цифре. Напишите программу, которая определяет интересное число или нет. Если число интересное, следует вывести – «Число интересное» иначе «Число неинтересное».
>
> Формат входных данных
> На вход программе подается целое трехзначное число.
>
> Формат выходных данных
> Программа должна вывести текст в соответствии с условием задачи.

Какое бы число не вводил выдает как интересное и думаю, что проблема в a6 но не понимаю как именно построить логику.

```
a = int(input())
a1 = a // 100
a2 = (a // 10) % 10
a3 = a % 10
a4 = min(a1, a2, a3)
a5 = max(a1, a2, a3)
a6 = a5 - a4
if a5 - a4 == a6:
    print('Число интересное')
elif a5 - a4 > a6:
    print('Число неинтересное')
```

Comment: Привел ниже последнюю версию, стало  интересно самому, как покороче сделать:-) Также привел начальный анализ ошибок. Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Comment: Вы не приняли ни один из ответов

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(input())
a = x // 100
b = x % 10
c = (x  // 10) % 10
z = (a + b + c) - min(a, b, c) - max(a,b, c)
if (max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)) == z:
    print('Число интересное')
else:
    print('Число неинтересное')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в простом самом была:-)
Как минимум, надо было `if (a5 - a4) == a6`, а второе условие на `else` поменять для начала (и дальше отлаживать, если что:-).

Но я бы так сделал для краткости в три строчки через списковое включение, где сразу строку разбиваем на цифры и заносим в список для сортировки, а потом сортируем этот список.

```
a = input()
l1 = sorted ([int(a[i]) for i in range(3)])
print('Число интересное') if (l1[2] - l1[0]) == l1[1] else print('Число неинтересное')
```

Comment: Можно еще вроде 2 строку заменить на `sorted(list(map(int, list(a))))`

Comment: @whatgenius, точно, так ещё проще и лучше! А если сделать: `l1 = sorted(list(map(int, list(input()))))`, то и строка 1 не нужна. Я просто `map` не изучал в курсе и опыта мало, а она полезна, конечно.

Comment: @whatgenius, так даже чуть короче, у вас 'list' 2 раза был: `l1 = sorted(map(int, list(input())))`